# How can link program that doesn't override getPlan method that is abstract method of Program interface(program.class) be instantiate as Program?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I was looking at PackagedProgram.java from org.apache.flink.client.program
and in following constructor:

```
PackagedProgram(File jarFile, List<URL> classpaths, String entryPointClassName, String... args)
```

there is some code I couldn't understand; please look below:

```
this.mainClass = loadMainClass(entryPointClassName, userCodeClassLoader);   

if (Program.class.isAssignableFrom(this.mainClass)) {
   Program prg = null;

   try {
      prg = InstantiationUtil.instantiate(this.mainClass.asSubclass(Program.class), Program.class);
   }
```

how can `this.mainClass` that doesn't override getPlan method that is abstract method of Program interface(program.class) and has only static main method be instantiate as Program?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please re-format your question. You may want to look at the [How do I ask a good question?-page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). [This meta-thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) explains code fromatting, which may improve the readability of your question.

Comment: thank you for comment. i revised accordingly.

Comment: `this.mainClass` must override `getPlan` -- otherwise, it can of course not be instantiated. Why do you think, `this.mainClass` does not implement `getPlan`?